# ReactJS -> problem with 'clearing' input forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I've got simple form.
Every time I try to fill a form, the rest of the fields clears.
In addition validation errors are displayed below each field instead of just one. How to fix this?
This how it looks before any action: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISwdb.png
And this how it looks after wrong data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYe4H.png

My constructor:

```js
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            foods: [{
                text: '',
                kcal: '',
                protein: '',
                carbohydrate: '',
                fat: ''
            }],
        };
```

Handlers and validation f():

```js
 handleKcalChange(event, index) {
        const foods = this.state.foods.slice();
        const value = event.target.value;


        foods[index] = {
            kcal: value,
            ...this.validateParam(value)
        }

        this.setState({
            foods: foods
        });
    }
```

```js
 handleProteinChange(event, index) {
        const foods = this.state.foods.slice();
        const value = event.target.value;

        foods[index] = {
            protein: value,
            ...this.validateParam(value)
        }

        this.setState({
            foods: foods
        });
    }
```

```js
validateParam = (paramNumber) => {
        if(paramNumber < 0) {
            return {
                validateStatus: 'error',
                errorMsg: 'Number can`t be smaller than 0.'
            }
        } else if(paramNumber > 1000) {
            return {
                validateStatus: 'error',
                errorMsg: 'Number is too big!'
            }
        } else {
            return {
                validateStatus: 'success',
                errorMsg: null
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you mind posting your code on jsfiddle or codepen so we can help you better?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sxd3mkqu/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue may be here in handleKcalEvent

```
foods[index] = {
            kcal: value,
            ...this.validateParam(value)
        }
```

you aren't changing the kcal of the object at the index, you're changing the object to a new object that just has kcal has a parameter, thereby erasing all of the other information (text, fat, carbs etc.)

try something like

```
const current = foods[index];
foods[index] = {...current,
                kcal: value,
                ...this.validateParam(value)
            }
```

Comment: Thanks man! It helped with auto-clearing fields. Now I have to correct "validating" functions

Comment: My guess is there is some error in the way you are displaying the error messages